# Grouping different things together so that they will all be activated/deactivated all at once with minimum code

Tags: c#

I don't know much about C# so I apologize in advance if my question has been answered elsewhere. I don't know what to search for.

I'm making a tic tac toe game in windows forms. I've set it up like this: each cell has 2 buttons(x and o) and two labels (X and O). Clicking one of the buttons will change the corresponding label's visible property to true while at the same time disabling (enable=false) the opposite button from being selected. There are 9 cells total. I also have a menu button (reset) that when clicked will enable all buttons and hide all labels so that the game may be re-played.

I'm looking for a way to reset all the items I want without having to individually type code for each item. Is there a way to group the items together so that they can all be fired at once with a minimum of code?

Source code is incomplete as I am still writing the program. I've posted the code for three cells.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tick_Tack_Toe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xLabel1.Visible = true;
            oButton1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void oButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            oLabel1.Visible = true;
            xButton1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void xButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xLabel2.Visible = true;
            oButton2.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void oButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            oLabel2.Visible = true;
            xButton2.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void resetToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender,
        EventArgs e)
        {
            xButton1.Enabled = true;
            oButton1.Enabled = true;
            xButton2.Enabled = true;
            oButton2.Enabled = true;
            xButton3.Enabled = true;
            oButton3.Enabled = true;
            xLabel1.Visible = false;
            oLabel1.Visible = false;
            xLabel2.Visible = false;
            oLabel2.Visible = false;
            xLabel3.Visible = false;
            oLabel3.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this?  `foreach(var control in this.Controls) if(control is Label) else if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))` etc.. etc...

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is to loop through the controls collection. Since you seem to have a standard on the naming of the controls, you can first narrow the collection down to only those whose name begins with 'o' or 'x'. Then, you can look at the type of control, and if it's a label you can hide it, and if it's a button you can enable it:

```
private void ResetControls()
{
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        // Only look at controls whose names begin with 'o' or 'x'
        if (control.Name.StartsWith("o") ||control.Name.StartsWith("x"))
        {
            // Hide it if it's a label
            if(control.GetType() == typeof(Label))
            {
                control.Visible = false;
            }
            // Enable it if it's a button
            else if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                control.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You mentioned that all your button and labels are inside their own panel control, which has it's own control collection. So you can modify the code above to first search for panel controls, then search the panel control's control collection for buttons and labels:

```
private void ResetControls()
{
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is Panel)
        {
            var panel = control as Panel;
            foreach (Control panelControl in panel.Controls)
            {
                // Only look at controls whose names begin with 'o' or 'x'
                if (panelControl.Name.StartsWith("o") || panelControl.Name.StartsWith("x"))
                {
                    // Hide it if it's a label
                    if (panelControl is Label)
                    {
                        panelControl.Visible = false;
                    }
                    // Enable it if it's a button
                    else if (panelControl is Button)
                    {
                        panelControl.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Note that this is just one possible solution to get you going, but certainly not the best. Normally the controls would be created at runtime, added to a collection of some sort (usually an array called `GameBoard` or something like that), and placed on the form all by code. Their click events would all be hooked up to the same method, which would do the right thing based on either control name or some data in the `Tag` field.

Comment: Thank you for the foreach loop. I didn't know that existed. They worked properly on an earlier version of my game but not on the latest version. I forgot to mention that each cell consists of a panel (just panel, not split panel) in which the buttons and labels are placed. So I have 9 panels. It goes form->panel->buttons and labels. How would I modify the loops to take into account the panels?

Comment: Updated answer with a possible solution where the controls are in a panel container.

Answer (score 0):

They are grouped together in the Controls array of the form.  Here is a simple example of how you can cycle through them:

```
private void doReset()
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            c.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
        {
            c.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can do some more intelligent logic in there for the specific controls if you like.  Something like adding a tag to each button if it gets picked up by the method or, naming each button in a certain way if it is to get picked up by the method.

Answer (score -3):

**Let's try following idea:**

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();

buttons.Add(xButton1)
buttons.Add(oButton1)
buttons.Add(xButton2)
buttons.Add(oButton2)
...

labels.Add(xLabel1)
labels.Add(oLabel1)
labels.Add(xLabel2)
labels.Add(oLabel2)
...

foreach(var ctr in buttons)
{
     ctr.Enabled = true;
}

foreach(var ctr in labels)
{
     ctr.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to manually enter them in.  Adding them to a list just defeats the purpose...

Comment: @Kyle, you are completely wrong. You have to understand that OP wants to minimun his code.

Comment: This code is shorter than yours: `foreach(var control in this.Controls) if(control is Label && control.Name.StartsWith("x", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`.  No need to manually add any control to a ridiculous `List<T>`

Comment: @Kyle There're 2 seperate things: duplicate code everywhere and duplicate code 1 place.
Why do you make sure that OP wants to foreach controls in the form?

Comment: why do you make sure the controls which OP wants to foreach will be start with "x" or "o"?

Comment: He can do whatever he wants.  I'm saying with your method, he has to manually change the code every time there's a new control.  By accessing `this.Controls`, there's no need to change the code.

Comment: no, I suggested the solution that OP should add all controls that he wants to foreach into the lists firstly because we really don't know them

Answer (score -3):

This is how I always do it.  If you give each button a different text value inside the click event you can do different things depending on the text value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tick_Tack_Toe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyButton.buttons = new List<MyButton>() { 
                new MyButton() { button = xButton1, label = xLabel1},
                new MyButton() { button = xButton2, label = xLabel2},
                new MyButton() { button = xButton3, label = xLabel3},
                new MyButton() { button = oButton1, label = oLabel1},
                new MyButton() { button = oButton2, label = oLabel2},
                new MyButton() { button = oButton3, label = oLabel3}
            };

            foreach (MyButton button in MyButton.buttons)
            {
                button.button.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
            }

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyButton button = sender as MyButton;

            button.label.Visible = true;
            button.button.Enabled = false;

            switch (button.button.Text)
            {
                case "X":
                    //enter your code here
                    break;
                case "Y":
                    //enter your code here
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void resetToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender,
        EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (MyButton button in MyButton.buttons)
            {
                button.button.Enabled = true;
                button.label.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyButton
    {
        public static List<MyButton> buttons { get; set; }
        public Button button { get; set; }
        public Label label { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add controls to a new list. :(  They're already stored in `this.Controls`

Comment: Kyle : It really doesn't add much memory since in is only a link to the object.  You are not duplicating the control.  It makes it much easier to enumerate through a group of controls.  Searching for a control by name takes much more time than enumerating through my list.  Simplifies the code tremendously.  Kyle you are absolutely wrong in this case.

Comment: The `Control` objects inside `this.Controls` already has the Name property, so searching is a breeze....  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx  `var interestingButton = this.Controls.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "interesting");`

Comment: But you can't associate the label and the button in one object.  And you don't have to use a WHERE to search through the list of controls. Does it make sense to enumerate through a 2000 controls to get 10 controls?  I've been programming for 40 years, have a BS,MS and plenty of programming experience at work.  I know what I'm saying.  My code is very efficient.

Comment: I'm pretty sure casting `sender` to `MyButton` will result in `sender` being `null`, since it's type is a `Button` (the click event is hooked up from the `Button`, not the `MyButton` class).